# Have new windows 10 as c:\ and Old hard drive as F:\

Tags: windows-7, windows

Son kindly installed new hard drive for me and I forgot to download the internet log in and passwords for my financials.
Is there anyway to access them on the old drive

Answer (score 0):

If it is as you say above, remove the new drive temporarily, put the old drive back, start it and recover whatever information you want to (say) a USB Hard drive that you can use with the new system. This method will recover information from anywhere on the old drive